# Error missing chunk number 0 in postgresql, I already figured out which field was corrupted

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm using **PostgreSQL 9.1.13 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-16ubuntu6) 4.8.2, 64-bit**

I have faced this error for many days, and I thought that I found a solution by creating a script to check all field in my database table, then update the corrupted column in the field to null.

It works fine for a while until I found this.

**I found a corrupted field then my script updated corrupted column to null, then I got this.**

```
# select * from comment where id = 7228707;
>> ERROR:  missing chunk number 0 for toast value 149171568 in pg_toast_8070962
```

***But, in the same time I can select by all table columns and got no error.***

```
# select id,comment,and,all,column,in,my,table from comment where id = 7228707;
```

to make sure that I select all table column I also do this

```
# SELECT string_agg(column_name, ', ') FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name ='comment' and table_schema='a1';
```

I also select all column name plus system column, it still appear no error at all. I got an error only when I do select * from table where corrupted field.

***So, any idea why is it being like this?***

***Are there any hidden column by Postgresql more than ctid,cmax,xmax,cmin,xmin,tableoid,oid ?***

***Is there any differences between using SELECT * and SELECT all,columns,name,in,the,table (all column name in the table)?***

Comment: Please add PostgreSQL version. Maybe [this thread](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/B0F87A6BC671B249AD1C6F7DF8ACA86C2AD086A2F2@ESGSCCMS0001.eapac.ericsson.se) can be useful to you. There is also question on SO on how to [fix corrupted db](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11030173/repair-corrupt-database-postgresql)

Comment: I did edit and add the version.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> PostgreSQL uses a fixed page size (commonly 8 kB), and does not allow tuples to span multiple pages. Therefore, it is not possible to store very large field values directly. To overcome this limitation, large field values are compressed and/or broken up into multiple physical rows. This happens transparently to the user, with only small impact on most of the backend code. The technique is affectionately known as TOAST (or "the best thing since sliced bread").

This means you have a large field which is stored outside the record page, and some of this field's data are corrupted.

The field subset you're selecting in your second query does not contain the corrupted field.

Comment: Isn't the point of the question the very fact that this second query selects **all the columns** and so shouldn't differ in its error from `select *` ?