# Rails migration error when adding index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord, postgis

I'm trying to add indexed columns to two existing tables.

```
add_column :places_1, :simple_geometry, :geometry, geographic: false, srid: 3857
add_index :places_1, :simple_geometry, using: :gist

add_column :places_2, :simple_geometry, :geometry, geographic: false, srid: 3857
add_index :places_2, :simple_geometry, using: :gist
```

The operation works fine on the first table, but I get an error when trying to add the index on the second table.

> PG::IoError: ERROR:  could not read block 180140 in file
>   "base/16384/1778170.1": Input/output error : CREATE  INDEX 
>   "index_places_2_on_simple_geometry" ON "places_2" USING gist
>   ("simple_geometry")

The column/index configuration is exactly the same, so I don't understand why it's failing on the second table.

Comment: It seems a corruption problem. Just in case, read this guide: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Corruption

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11030173/repair-corrupt-database-postgresql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was indeed some sort of corruption, as I got another "could not read block" error when I tried to pg_dump the table:

> pg_dump: Error message from server: ERROR:  could not read block
>   180140 in file "base/16384/1778170.1": Input/output error

Thankfully, this is a local dev database so I don't care about the data. After truncating the table and re-populating it from production the issues went away.

If I have future problems with the database I will start fresh with a new database, but for now flushing the data from that one table seemed to do the trick.