# Why I have this problem : Could not read block in file problem?

Tags: postgresql

I have a database that was corrupted for some reason. I keep getting this error whenever I try to select all the rows:

> ERROR: could not read block 1110 in file "base/217100/217551": read only 4096 of 8192 bytes

For this table I only have 1 primary key and another unique field.

When I tried to select all the rows ordered by primary key I can retrieve all the keys. If not I still get the error.

Comment: You somehow got your database corrupted. Restore from a backup.

Comment: Check this: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44508/error-could-not-read-block-x-of-relation-base-y-z

Comment: Formatted error section

Answer (score 0):

I am sharing my answers here for better reach.

Detailed tries and steps, visit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74100928/1609952

```
tar -zcvf my_backup.tar.gz /var/lib/postgresql/xx/main/xx
Extract the corrupted file from TAR.
Replace it in original locationbase/12345/12345.1.
Stop & Start PGSQL
```